# How to popup a text file in JavaScript on client side

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript and I would to like to popup a text file on client-side whenever I clicked on a particular button. Is it possible to achieve it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

The security issues might not be your concern, but they are the browser's :). The client's browser won't let you do that because it is a security threat to the client.

Comment: Also, I bet there is another way to accomplish what you want to do without opening a file on the user's computer.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is you want to do. If you just want to give them editable test, use the <textarea> tag in html, and load into it in JS. If you want them to download a static test file, you can just give them a link to it. If you want to generate a text file on the clientside, you can't do this in JS, but you can do it in Flash using the FileReference class (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html). Alternatively you can generate the file in the server side using a language of your choice and prompt them to download it.

Comment: Thanks for ur respone Zaven my need is quiet simple i have  a button on my form and when i clicked on this button ,a txt file gets popup not only on serverside but on client side as well..

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that. What sort of information does this file contain and why do you want it to pop up?

Comment: sorry for late reply ,its just a txt file nothing specific inside it. My actual idea is to open a pdf file whenever i clicke on button

Answer (score 1):

Nope that is not possible for **security reasons**. Access client files with javascript would have lead to serious security issues if it was possible.

I know you can use [FSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx) in bad IE browser but you should avoid doing that.

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz but suppose security issues are not my concern that how do i achieve the above